# The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected in WebSockets

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm new to WebSockets, I have written one sample C# console application for web socket client and server. When connecting to the server from the client, I receive the above exception if I specify the HTTPListenerPrefix URl as IP address for either client or server (but not both). If I specify the machine name instead, then everything worked as expected.

Server code:

```
    //server.Start("http://inpsservice10:80/");
    server.Start("http://131.163.140.92:80/");
}

public async void Start(string httplistenerPrefix)
{
    HttpListener httplistner = new HttpListener();
    httplistner.Prefixes.Add(httplistenerPrefix);
    httplistner.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening");
    while(true)
    {
        HttpListenerContext httplistencontext = await httplistner.GetContextAsync();
        if (httplistencontext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
            ProcessRequest(httplistencontext);
        else
        {
            httplistencontext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
            httplistencontext.Response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
Connect("ws://131.163.140.92:80/").Wait();
private static async Task Connect(string uri)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    ClientWebSocket webSocket = null;
    try
    {
        webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
        await webSocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(uri), CancellationToken.None); //i'm getting exception here.
        await Task.WhenAll(Receive(webSocket), Send(webSocket));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connect: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Potentially silly question, but if you have .NET on both client and server, why websockets at all?  It's possibly not the right solution to your problem.

Comment: Do you mean to say that so long as both client and server use the same host (IP or name) it works, but mixing hosts (IP on one, name on the other) causes the exception?

Comment: Yes, if i mix the combination i get the exception else everything worked well.

Comment: @James Thorpe: It is not a small requirement, this is a sample application based on the solution i have something to do. So, please let me know if the IP combination is possible in WebSockets. Please don't assume it to be a silly question. Let me know the solution if you know the answer.

Comment: The "silly question" was referring to my question of "why websockets?" - it's a common term for when you ask something that might turn out to have an obvious answer that you didn't see at first.  If you have genuine reasons for wanting to do this, that's fair enough.